# Odd Regex Issue with grep Bash

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, grep

I've got an odd regex issue with grep. Please know I'm very new to regex and have just been trial and erroring to get my result.

I've got the following file on two different Ubuntu machines.

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 14 Mar 2222 15:10:28 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=soekfifnowmds3278xks;Path=/
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 743
Server:

{
      "testName": "Test\r",
      "tagString": "",
      "description": "TestTest\r",
      "status": "READY",
      "ignoreSampleCount": 0,
      "targetHosts": "\r\n\r",
      "useRampUp": true,
      "rampUpType": "THREAD",
      "threshold": "D",
      "scriptName": "test.py",
      "duration": 60000,
      "runCount": 0,
      "agentCount": 1,
      "vuserPerAgent": 1,
      "processes": 1,
      "rampUpInitCount": 0,
      "rampUpInitSleepTime": 0,
      "rampUpStep": 1,
      "rampUpIncrementInterval": 1000,
      "threads": 1,
      "progressMessage": "",
      "testComment": "",
      "scriptRevision": 400,
      "region": "NONE",
      "samplingInterval": 1,
      "param": "",
      "createdDate": "Jun 27, 2222 3:10:28 PM",
      "lastModifiedDate": "Jun 27, 2347 3:10:28 PM",
      "id": 21
    }
```

It's in the JSON format but I'm not using jq to parse it because the file consists of other details (like return headers since I'm querying this data from an API) which aren't in JSON and jq will pop out an error if I even try to parse the file using it. Hence, I'm using grep.

Now, I need to get out the id from this data (just the numeric part, in this case, 21). Perhaps there's a better way to do this, but till now I was using

`cat File | grep '"id": [0-9]*' | grep -o [0-9]*`

And it gives me the right answer. However, for some reason, the behaviour was inconsistent. Like I mentioned in the beginning, I've got the exact same JSON data on two Ubuntu machines. But when I run the same command to fetch out the id from one of the machines, the above comamnd doesn't work! I get no result as though grep could find nothing.

The problem I found was in the second grep command. On the machine on which the above command was not working, I replaced it with `grep -o [0-9].` and it fetched it fine. But I know that the moment the id runs into more than 2 digits, it'll stop working. But the * is not working just on that system! While on the other, it's working for any number of digits flawlessly!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! If we're not able to figure out why it's behaving inconsistently, perhaps you could please provide me with another grep that would fetch me the same.

Comment: What error is `jq` throwing it should be pretty straight forward

Comment: So the file with the JSON output, doesn't ONLY have that. It has some stuff above like HTTP 1.1/100 Continue and things like that. So it pops an error if I try to parse it with no filters basically telling me it's not a pure JSON file, which is true.

Comment: Yes, it did. Just testing it out. Thank you very much. Am editing my original post now which will show why jq won't work for the file.

Comment: Can you post the `cURL` command you are using? You can tweak it to emit `JSON` without containing the header information

Comment: Yes. It's a curl to accept some sample data from a service. It's a simple curl call like `curl -u username:password http://example.com/api/sample > sample.data`

Comment: You can remove the `-i` flag if you are using in the `cURL` which includes all the header information above `JSON`, without that the output should be plain `JSON` which you can feed to `jq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GNU grep` with its [Perl Compatible Regular Expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) capabilities enabled with the `-P` flag and print only the matching entry using `-o` flag.

```
grep -oP '"id": \K[0-9]+' file
21
```

where the `\K` escape sequence stands for

> \K: [This sequence resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously matched characters are not included in the final matched sequence.](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/pcre-regex-spotlight-k)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NRBt9J/1)

---

You can remove the -i flag if you are using in the `cURL` which includes all the header information as in the above `JSON`, without that the output should be plain `JSON` which you can feed to `jq` as

```
curl ... | jq '.id' 
21
```